# Omnipay-Stripe storing creditcard details from form to database

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, credit-card, omnipay

I'm using Omnipay-stripe in laravel 5.2 and is working fine. I want to store credit card details of customers to pre-populate stripe popup with creditcard details while making another payment.

Comment: You may want to start by reading [these rules on storing cardholder data (pdf)](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf) if you haven't already.

Comment: I want to populate previously used card like every shopping websites does. Then how can I do it? Is there any method for it in Omnipay-Stripe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the card against stripe using createCard which will get you back a card reference. You can then use that instead of the actual card data when making a purchase.

You should be calling create customer as well. Check the documentation in the class docblocks

Comment: Does onmipay provide method named "createCard"?

Comment: Yes it does. It's not available for all gateways but you can call supportsCreateCard () to find out